# Single comma separated tuple inside of a list

Tags: python, pyodbc

Using pyodbc I'm working on dealing with executing stored procedures with outputs.

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=' + driver + ';PORT=1433;SERVER=' + server +
                      ';PORT=1443;DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password)
cmd = conn.cursor()
sql = """\
Too long to post
"""
params = ('EOXH39020220', 'EOXH39020245', 'EOXH3E360011')
for item in params:
    cmd.execute(sql, item)
    rst = cmd.fetchall()
    print(rst)
conn.close
```

The output of a particular stored procedure I am testing with produces the following:

```
[(False, 1, 3, 2, 967, 6, 'ABC-DE-FGHI', 'LOREM', 'IPSUM', 'CLASS PRODUCT', 'F/P', 'LABELDESCRIPTION', 'N/A', 'DESCRIPTION', 'ASL66', 'ASL10', '3FE50712BA', 'ABC-DE-FGHI', 'PO', 'ITEM#', 'OEM#', 'F/P', '1')]
[(False, 1, 4, 1, 967, 7, 'ABC-DE-FGHI', 'LOREM', 'IPSUM', 'CLASS PRODUCT', 'F/P', 'LABELDESCRIPTION', 'N/A', 'DESCRIPTION', 'ASL66', 'ASL10', '3FE50712BA', 'ABC-DE-FGHI', 'PO', 'ITEM#', 'OEM#', 'F/P', '1')]
[(False, 1, 4, 2, 967, 8, 'ABC-DE-FGHI', 'LOREM', 'IPSUM', 'CLASS PRODUCT', 'F/P', 'LABELDESCRIPTION', 'N/A', 'DESCRIPTION', 'ASL66', 'ASL10', '3FE50712BA', 'ABC-DE-FGHI', 'PO', 'ITEM#', 'OEM#', 'F/P', '1')]
```

I can't use `.split` on it since it's not really a string.  How can I split up the contents of a tuple inside of a list?  What I am trying to do is break the results back out into variables to use.  I'm not getting the results I expect to see.  Ex:

```
testlist = [(False, 1, 3, 2, 967, 6, 'ABC-DE-FGHI', 'LOREM', 'IPSUM', 'CLASS 1 PRODUCT', 'F/P', 'DESCRIPTION', 'N/A', 'DESCRIPTION', 'ASL66', 'ASL10', '3FE50712BA', 'ABC-DE-FGHI', 'PO', 'ITEM#', 'OEM#', 'F/P', '1')]
for i in testlist[0]:
    print(testlist[0][i])
```

results:

> False
>   1
>   2
>   3

As suggested by roganjosh, I completely missed what I needed in my loop.
first 5 items ex:

```
testlist = [(False, 1, 3, 2, 967, 6, 'ABC-DE-FGHI', 'LOREM', 'IPSUM', 'CLASS PRODUCT', 'F/P', 'LABELDESCRIPTION', 'N/A', 'DESCRIPTION', 'ASL66', 'ASL10', '3FE50712BA', 'ABC-DE-FGHI', 'PO', 'ITEM#', 'OEM#', 'F/P', '1')]

newlist = []

for x in testlist[0]:
    newlist.append(x)

print(newlist[:5])
```

> [False, 1, 3, 2, 967]

Comment: What dictionary are you talking about? I don't see anything remotely `dict`-like here. Can you give an example of your desired output, per the [MCVE] requirements?

Comment: Also, `conn.close` will not close the connection. You need to call the method using parentheses: `conn.close()`

Comment: Ok, my initial comment was just re-stating the title, which I lost sight of in the question body. It seems you know what kind of result you have (which isn't a dict) so is your question how to get the query to return a dictionary, or do you just want a list of results without the tuple?

Comment: Why do you think you need to split anything? You have a list of tuples, each tuple is one row of the results of the stored procedure. Loop through the list and access the tuple elements that you want.

Comment: Also, if you know the procedure only returns one row, just use `cmd.fetchone()` instead of `cmd.fetchall()`. Then you don't have to loop through a list.

Comment: @roganjosh I want to be able to access each element of the tuple so I can reassign them to new variables.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from doing that currently. `rst[0][0]` should give you `False`. Just index the tuple that is at the 0th index of the list that's returned. `rst = list(rst[0])` should just give you back a flat list.

Comment: @roganjosh Ive tried that.  When I do something like `for i in testlist[0]: print(testlist[0][i]) I don't get the results I would expect; a printed line of each item in the tuple.  Ill update my question.

Comment: Well no, you wouldn't because `testlist[0]` is not a dictionary so `testlist[0][i]` doesn't make sense. `for i in testlist[0]: print(i)` would do what you expect though. `i` is not some incrementing integer, that would be `for i, value in enumerate(testlist[0]): print(testlist[0][i])`; instead, `i` is just the name you assigned to the _value_ stored at each index.

Comment: @roganjosh fml, how did I miss that :-/  Post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit confused but we established the issue in comments. Your title is mostly accurate in what's being returned from `fetchall()`: a list containing a single tuple, *not* a dictionary as you go on to state.

`fetchall()` is generally used when you expect multiple matches, where each row would be a tuple in the list (so you might consider using `fetchone()` as stated by @Barmar in the comments if you're always getting one result).

In the comments, you state that you tried the following but it didn't work:

```
for i in testlist[0]: 
    print(testlist[0][i])
```

It won't - `testlist[0]` gives you access to the tuple, but then you try to access that as though it were a dictionary with `i` as the key. Instead, `i` is the name that is being assigned to each item in that tuple.

The solution is as simple as doing:

```
for i in testlist[0]: 
    print(i)
```

Comment: My apologies about the content.  I actually corrected the title before it ever got traction but didn't think to look at the content.  Thanks again for the help.